# RequireJS dependency undefined in callback method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I started to use `RequireJS`, the dependency loads fine but in the callback method all dependencies are `undefined`.

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        angular: '../lib/angular/angular',
        myApp: 'app',
        states: 'app-states',
        controllers: 'controllers',
        filters: 'filters',
        services: 'services',
        oauth2: 'oauth2'
        //async: 'lib/require/async'
    },
    shim: {
        'myApp': {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        'states' : {
            deps: ['angular', 'myApp']
        },
        'controllers': {
            deps: ['angular', 'myApp']
        },
        'filters': {
            deps: ['angular', 'myApp']
        },
        'services': {
            deps: ['angular', 'myApp']
        }       
    }
});

require(['angular', 'myApp', 'states', 'controllers', 'filters', 'services'], function(angular, myApp, states, controllers, filters, services) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('requireJs done');
    console.log(angular);
    console.log(myApp);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
});
```

If I just require `angular`, the callback method is not called. I was wondering why.

```js
require(['angular', function(angular) {
    console.log("requireJS done");
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not exporting any values from those libraries.  For shims you need to specify the variable to be exported before you can reference them.  Since you're not exporting anything, the variables are set to null.

Exporting looks like this:

```
shim: {
    "angular": {
        exports: "angular"
    }
}
```

AMD/Requirejs works by pulling a value out of the files that it loads and setting that to the named argument in the callback function.  For normal AMD files, thats whatever the return value of the function passed to define is, or the object within define.  But for shims, you need to pick a variable, usually the namespace of the libary.  That allows you to simulate AMD for namespace based libaries

You can see the [documentation section on shims](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, the array of dependencies should the be the first argument.

Try

```
require(['angular'], function(angular) {
    console.log("requireJS done");
});
```

Comment: You're right but after fixing the syntax, `console.log(angular)` still returns `undefined` in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I had to export some library, to be available in my callback.

```
shim: {
    'angular': {
        exports: 'angular'
    }
}
```